# How can take locale from url in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I want to apply locale in an API, but it returns the `ar` language only. I want to take locale from url [ar or en] like : `localhost/mertaah/api/en/settings` it must take `en` locale but it take `ar` all the time

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class ApplyAPILocale
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \Closure                 $next
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        app()->setLocale($request->header('locale') ?? 'ar');

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the content of `$request->header('locale')` ? the header is not the URL. How are your routes defined?

Comment: protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {
        $locale = request()->segment(2);
        if (!in_array($locale, config('app.locales'))) {
            $locale = '';
        }

        Route::prefix('api/'.$locale)
            //  ->prefix($locale)
             ->middleware('api')
             ->namespace($this->namespace)
             ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    }

Comment: Don't add a comment. Edit the question and add the additional information in there.

Comment: I found the solution,Thank you for helping me

Answer (score -1):

this is the solution that help me to solve the problem 
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/pass-locale-to-url